# Actions class operations inside iframe(Java-Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

I am Currently inside a iframe and I am trying to perform Click and Right Click Operations using Actions class. At the time of executing the script the click and Right click operations are performed on the incorrect elements(Operations are performed on the elements below the Expected Elements). The locators that I am using are correct.

How do I perform Click and Right Click operations inside a iFrame using Actions Class or do we have an alternate way

Code:- I have switched to the iframe

```
**Click Operation:-** 

Actions actions = new Actions(driver.get());
            actions.moveToElement(wait.get().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath(currentObject)))));
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            actions.click();
            actions.build().perform();

**Right Click Operation:-** 

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver.get()); 
        actions.moveToElement(wait.get().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(currentObject)))); 
        actions.contextClick(); 
        actions.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you switch your driver to the right frame?

Comment: Yes I switched to the correct frame, because it were clicking on incorrect elements inside the frame

Comment: Use contextClick(element) instead of contextClick()

Comment: Even that is not working

Actions actions = new Actions(driver.get());
   actions.moveToElement(
     wait.get().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(currentObject))));
   actions.contextClick(driver.get().findElement(By.xpath(currentObject)));
   actions.build().perform();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).